# select checkbox using jquery before it is shown in UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, checkbox

Here is my case:

I am reading data from mysql db and then displaying it in table using jsp, servlet and jquery.
I am creating dynamic row. My problem is I want to select checkbox based on value from DB. Here is sample code:

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'FetchQAStatus',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'text/html',

                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    var tbody = $('#edit_table_body');
                      $.each(data, function(key,value) { 
                          tbody.append('<tr><td>'+value['id']+'</td><td><select      name="project" id="project" class="project"><option value="Geo">Geo</option>'+
                                '<option value="UAC">UAC</option></select></td><td><input type="text" name="jira" id="jira" class="freshblue" value="'+
                                value['jira']+'"/>'+'<td><textarea name="summary" id="summary" >'+value['summary']+'</textarea></td><td>'+
                                '<input type="text" name="status" id="status" class="freshblue" value="'+value['status']+'"/></td>'+
                                '<td><textarea name="comments" id="comments" >'+value['comments']+'</textarea></td><td><input type="checkbox" '+
                                'name="prod_deploy" id="prod_deploy">'+
                                '</td></tr>');

                            $(this).find("input#prod_deploy").prop("checked", true);

                      });



                        $(".edit_status").slideToggle();

                },
```

But this is not selecting checkbox, as checkbox is still not visible/loaded on UI.
Please help

Comment: not visible or not selected?

Comment: you're adding numerous elements with the same ID; that's not gonna end well. also, is the context `this` inside of the `each()` method the same as the `tbody`? You're adding your new elements to that but checking inside `$(this)` for the newly added elements... not sure what you're trying to do exactly there.

Comment: @heinob Not visible, I mean I am creating elements but its not shown in UI

Comment: @Derek please ignore id part, I know its not correct, I am not using it in my code. each() method is basically for all the data from DB, I am iterating each row and then creating a row in the table. Hope this clarifies

Answer (score 0):

You can do either this:

```
...
var content = '<tr>'
  + '<td>' + value['id'] + '</td>'
  + '<td>'
    + '<select name="project" id="project" class="project">'
      + '<option value="Geo">Geo</option>'
      + '<option value="UAC">UAC</option>'
    + '</select>'
  + '</td>'
  + '<td>'
    + '<input type="text" name="jira" id="jira" class="freshblue" value="' + value['jira'] + '"/>'
  + '</td>'
  + '<td>'
    + '<textarea name="summary" id="summary" >' + value['summary'] + '</textarea>'
  + '</td>'
  + '<td>'
    + '<input type="text" name="status" id="status" class="freshblue" value="' + value['status'] + '"/>'
  + '</td>'
  + '<td>'
    + '<textarea name="comments" id="comments" >' + value['comments'] + '</textarea>'
  + '</td>'
  + '<td>'
    + '<input type="checkbox" name="prod_deploy" id="prod_deploy" checked>'
  + '</td>'
+ '</tr>';

tbody.append(content);
$(content).find('input#prod_deploy').prop('checked', true);
```

or this:

```
...
var content = '<tr>'
  + '<td>' + value['id'] + '</td>'
  + '<td>'
    + '<select name="project" id="project" class="project">'
      + '<option value="Geo">Geo</option>'
      + '<option value="UAC">UAC</option>'
    + '</select>'
  + '</td>'
  + '<td>'
    + '<input type="text" name="jira" id="jira" class="freshblue" value="' + value['jira'] + '"/>'
  + '</td>'
  + '<td>'
    + '<textarea name="summary" id="summary" >' + value['summary'] + '</textarea>'
  + '</td>'
  + '<td>'
    + '<input type="text" name="status" id="status" class="freshblue" value="' + value['status'] + '"/>'
  + '</td>'
  + '<td>'
    + '<textarea name="comments" id="comments" >' + value['comments'] + '</textarea>'
  + '</td>'
  + '<td>'
    + '<input type="checkbox" name="prod_deploy" id="prod_deploy" checked>' // <== notice the "checked" attribute here
  + '</td>'
+ '</tr>';

tbody.append(content);
```

Comment: None of these are working. I think the problem is this table is still not shown. It will basically load after last line which is  $(".edit_status").slideToggle();

Answer (score 0):

This is solved. Posting answer incase someone is looking for:

```
  var prodCheck = (value['isProd'] == true) ? "checked":"";
                          var content = '<tr><td>'+value['id']+'</td><td><select name="project" id="project" class="project"><option value="Geo">Geo</option>'+
                            '<option value="UAC">UAC</option></select></td><td><input type="text" name="jira" id="jira" class="freshblue" value="'+
                            value['jira']+'"/>'+'<td><textarea name="summary" id="summary" >'+value['summary']+'</textarea></td><td>'+
                            '<input type="text" name="status" id="status" class="freshblue" value="'+value['status']+'"/></td>'+
                            '<td><textarea name="comments" id="comments" >'+value['comments']+'</textarea></td><td><input type="checkbox" '+
                            'name="prod_deploy" class="prod_deploy" '+prodCheck+'>'+
                            '</td></tr>';
                          tbody.append(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that you can display a checkbox as selected before displaying it.

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="true" />
```

Now append as above where you want to display a checkbox as selected.